# How to Stop Hero (Character) Movement in SpriteKit?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

The main function to walk the Hero this function inside *Player.Swift* I want to stop walking with Touching position.

This function would be running continues inside *GameScene.swift*

I want to stop my Hero when user tap to the target Position but after stop Hero whenever user tap on new target location hero moves with new position and stop again.

Here is my code:

```
    { 
     override init() {

    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "characters")
    let texture = atlas.textureNamed("player_ft1")
    texture.filteringMode = .Nearest

    sprite = AnimatedSprite(texture: texture)

   // sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

    super.init()

    addChild(sprite)
    name = "player"

    // 1
    var minDiam = min(sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height)
    minDiam = max(minDiam-16.0, 4.0)
    let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: minDiam/2.0)

    // 2
    physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    // 3
    physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
    physicsBody.restitution = 1
    physicsBody.friction = 0
    physicsBody.linearDamping = 0
    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boundary
    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boundary | PhysicsCategory.Wall | PhysicsCategory.Water
    //physicsBody.dynamic=false

    // 4
    self.physicsBody = physicsBody

    sprite.facingBackAnim = AnimatedSprite.createAnimWithPrifix("player",suffix: "ft")
    sprite.facingForwardAnim = AnimatedSprite.createAnimWithPrifix("player",suffix: "bk")
    sprite.facingSideAnim = AnimatedSprite.createAnimWithPrifix("player",suffix: "lt")
    sprite.runAction(sprite.facingBackAnim)
}
func moveToward(target: CGPoint) {
   // _Lastlocation
    let targetVector = (target - position).normalized() * 150.0
        physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(point: targetVector)
    faceCurrentDirection()
 }
```

Comment: It's unclear from the text what the actual problem and the desired behavior are. Please add more detailed description of what happens and what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Please explain your self more clearly , add example if you can.